# How to disable Mac's generic Option-Command-W?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I end up accidentally hitting it because I have a similar shortcut for something else. I was hoping to disable Option-Cmd-W. I am fine disabling it only for one app specifically, or for all apps, whichever is easier. I'm on MacBook Pro, Catalina.

What software can I buy that could do it?

(Or maybe I just missed some menu option?)

Note: I'm talking about the shortcut that is set by Apple, not by any application. It's mentioned here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236. Chrome is not showing this key assignment in its menu (it has Close All listed in the menu, but it seems as if it's unassigned). And yet, when I followed the accepted answer, I did manage to disable this.

Comment: There are a lot of Q&As about how to rebind/reassign keys in this site. Can you try whether some of the answers fit? If you can‘t get it to work please edit the question and list the things which didn‘t work.

Comment: Ah so sorry for the confusing explanation. I should have clarified that I'm asking about Mac keyboard shortcut, not app-specific keyboard shortcut. Updated the question. I didn't find any duplicates for this particular issue.

Comment: From your question: „I am fine disabling it only for one app specifically, or for all apps, whichever is easier.“. And the application to look for is called Karabiner.

Comment: "For one app specifically": Oh I didn't realize that even though Chrome menu does not show that Close All = Option-Cmd-W, by adding this menu in Keyboard shortcuts I manage to disable it! Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: Alternatively, change the 'other' key shortcut that is similar!

Comment: @nohillside so Karabiner can disable keyboard shortcut commands such as command w and command q? Can you please tell me how to do that in a chat room or in these comments?

Comment: @arien Please have a look at existing questions about Karabiner. If you can’t find any useful answers there, ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the *keyboard shortcut* for **Close All** on the **File** menu of **Google Chrome**, this can be does in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

Click the **[+]** button and fill in the *sheet* that appears.

For this example, I changed it to: **⌥⌘/**

[image]